# How to manually uninstall Windows program Livigent?

Tags: windows, uninstall

I have a program called Livigent installed on my computer. It is an internet filter. Basically, I do not know the password, and I want to uninstall it. But to uninstall it, it opens its own uninstaller. Now, the uninstaller asks for the password (naturally) and I don't know it. Therefore I cannot uninstall it.
I have tried to use various third party uninstallers, but the way they all work is by opening the default uninstaller, which asks for the password. I tried with iobit uninstaller, and there was a force uninstall tool, and when I tried to use it it asked for the location of the program. Now, I don't know where the executive file of this program is, I checked program files, and found nothing. There is no shortcut in the start menu that can show me where it is... Nothing. This program is a ghost on my computer, and the only place it shows up is in the uninstall screen and on Task Manager.

So my question is, how can I possibly uninstall this program???

I'm really disappointed, coz although I am system administrator, I do not have total control over my system :(

(This is why I usually use Linux )

Comment: Why don't you ask the person who installed what the password is?

Comment: Coz they don't remember it

Comment: Install [ProcessHacker](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/), find the program when it is running and hover over the process name. It will show the full path of the exe.

Comment: And try looking in `C:\users\user\appdata\local\lvgic` http://www.shouldiremoveit.com/livigent-ic-x64-174127-program.aspx

Comment: You make contradicting statements. You are the system admin and you don't know your own password??

Comment: I didn't install the program. Someone else with admin rights did. Now they don't remember the password

Comment: "The only place it shows up is in the uninstall screen". So doesn't it even start with the OS? I'm confused because you reacted to suggestions to track the program when it runs. Does it start or not?

Comment: Oops, forgot to mention that it also shows up in task manager. Will edit now

Comment: Maybe it's a service. If so, you should be able to disable it with your admin credentials i.e. without any third party password. You should do this before you delete any of its files manually.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski how can I do that? Not much of an expert in services..

Comment: I don't use Windows but I believe you should run `services.msc` and find your way from there.

Comment: Use Microsoft SysInternals Process Explorer and Autoruns to identify the program's load points. It probably uses Winsock entries to analyze network traffic for filtering purposes.

Comment: Contact Their support the'll be able to help you, I had very good experience with them.
The'll probably be able to make your whatsapp work or uninstall it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're probably using "Livigent Content Filter".

You mentioned in a comment on the question that nobody remembers the password.

## What to do

Click Livigent's "Settings" button. This should take you to a login screen. Now click the "Forgot my password" button.

[(Source.)](http://www.livigent.com/support-details/p-2/)

## If that fails

Livigent isn't free. But the consolation prize is that this entitles you to tech support.

If the "Forgot my password" button doesn't work, go to http://www.livigent.com and click "Contact". You'll see all their contact information. It'd be best to phone them, if you can; but, if this is impractical, you can also contact them electronically.

## Question

Why do you want to uninstall Livigent anyway? Based on what I've heard, it sounds to me like it's good at what it does.

Please leave a comment below.

Comment: Because I am running android emulator, so someone who I share the computer with can have WhatsApp on my computer since he doesn't have a smartphone. And the program was blocking WhatsApp's connection on the emulator.

Answer (score -1):

Observe the process when it starts from task manager and open the file location there you will be able to delete it manually.

Comment: You'd also want to look for the relevant registry keys. And hope it dosen't do something crazy like, I donno, low level special drivers.